# trouble installing flask_cors and pillow on mac

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, anaconda

I'm very new to python and just downloaded Anaconda and installed Pycharm. Now that all this is installed I'm stuck with Flask_cors and Pillow, which are needed for a project.
You can see the error in the screenshot below.

I've tried to install via pip command in terminal, and also specifying the target folder (like described in another post) or updating Flask and Pillow via Anaconda, nothing seems to work.

FYI I'm running Mac OS 10.12.6

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using anaconda. So, I'd suggest you start from scratch, make a new environment and follow this route:

- Deactive your old `conda` environment

```
conda deactivate
```

- Make a new conda environment

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```

- Activate your new environment

```
conda activate myenv
```

- Install your dependencies. Since it's a `conda` environment, you should use conda commands to install the dependencies. See [here](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) why.

```
conda install -c anaconda flask
conda install -c conda-forge flask-cors
conda install -c anaconda pillow
```

Now try again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.
So I've followed the steps and installed the requirements, Pycharm still tells me that the "package requirements are not satisfied".
I guess I'll have to point Pycharm to the folder where the packages are installed?

Comment: All these packages are listed in Project Interpreter settings, right?

Please try to remove this interpreter from IDE, then do `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. |` Invalidate and Restart and add the interpreter again. Wait for IDE to finish updating stubs and check again.

Comment: Open an interpreter in your terminal (in the new environment) and try to import flask and flask cors. If they don't throw `ImportError`, then it's a pycharm issue.

Comment: Hmm it looks like it's a pycharm issue indeed. 
I will look into the issue and post the solution once I've got it to work.

Thanks for your input so far !